# Removing the scroll bar from a select element

Tags: html

Is there a way to remove the scroll bar in a select element with the 'multiple' attribute enabled?

```
<select name="test" multiple>
    <option value="foo">Foo</option>
    <option value="bar">Bar</option>
    <option value="baz">Baz</option>
</select>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hide vertical scrollbar in <select> element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4531269/hide-vertical-scrollbar-in-select-element)

Comment: Please check this out!!!
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4531269/hide-vertical-scrollbar-in-select-element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should **not** remove it actually for **accessibility reasons**. If you do so, it would look like a `textarea` rather than a multi selectbox.

Comment: I don't disagree but I'm curious as to whether it is even possible.

Comment: @Darrell Brogdon: I did search for the solution but found none. Probably for the obvious reasons, it is not possible. Let's see if someone could come up with a solution.