# Hide vertical scrollbar in <select> element

Tags: html, css

Hello I have select box with multiple choices and I need to hide the vertical scrollbar, is it possible?

```
<select name="sCat" multiple="true">
<!-- My Option Here -->
</select>
```

Okey, but how then I can achieve an effect where I can select item from list that has ID and then use jQuery to manage this id.click functions? What element I should use then?

Comment: Not that I'm aware. You'll need to make a "Control" yourself (i.e. simulate the effect using a div and a button with a click event or something [not to mention keyboard shortcuts]).

Comment: "Okey, but how then I can achieve an effect where I can select item from list that has ID and then use jQuery to manage this id.click functions? What element I should use then?" A option tag doesn't have an ID either. I think you mean an attribute in which you store the ID. If so, you can use any tag that supports an attribute to put the value in: radio, checkbox, button. In theory even textbox.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

This is where we appreciate all the power of CSS3:

```css
.bloc {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: solid grey 1px;
}

.bloc select {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: -5px -20px -5px -5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bloc">
  <select name="year" size="5">
    <option value="2010">2010</option>
    <option value="2011">2011</option>
    <option value="2012" SELECTED>2012</option>
    <option value="2013">2013</option>
    <option value="2014">2014</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

### Fiddle

Comment: Better to use clip than margin.

Comment: Nice, but a little improvment would be to use a span instead of a div, just in case browser doesn't support inline-block (yeah, I must be talking about a microsoft's ungifted baby).

Comment: `This is where we appreciate all the power of CSS3`. Could someone tell me where the CSS3 is here?

Comment: It's not really css3, you could do the same in CSS2 or (with tweaks) even 1. In fact, it's more of a hack than a real styling of select, which is still not stylable.

Comment: So what happens in the case that you have more than 5 elements? They just get hidden?

Comment: @MikeYoung as the scrollbar is just moved into an invisble area you still have full scroll behaviour using any keyboard, mouse or touch device.

Answer (score 94):

I know this thread is somewhat old, but there are a lot of really hacky answers on here, so I'd like to provide something that is a lot simpler and a lot cleaner:

```
select {
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

As you can see in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zc4omj6q/1/), this solution provides you with flexibility if you don't know the exact number of select options you are going to have. It hides the scrollbar in the case that you don't need it without hiding possible extra option elements in the other case. Don't do all this hacky overlapping `div` stuff. It just makes for unreadable markup.

Comment: No problem, always should answer with answers when you have them. It's what SO is all about man.

Comment: Why this answer has not been selected as the best answer ?

Comment: Depending on your situation, you can also populate the value of the `size` attribute with the number of options using a variable

Comment: @JuanLanus well I guess I had a misunderstanding of what auto means. Apparently, auto just leaves it up to the browser to decide what to do with the scrollbar, and Firefox handles it differently than everyone else, which is super lame. See the section on Syntax in this link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow

Comment: @Mike Young Seems to me that the select element does not react to the overflow style because its implementation is half baked.

Comment: This is a nice but Mozilla really needs to get with the program.

Comment: This works just as well as the most popular answer and is much cleaner.

Comment: To override the user agent stylesheet defaults for `select:-internal-list-box`, you need to add the `!important` property. So IMHO the "correct" answer would be `select { overflow-y: auto !important; }`.

Comment: `!important` is rarely needed if you use the correct selector specificity

Answer (score 22):

No, you can't control the look of a select box in such detail.

A select box is usually displayed as a dropdown list, but there is nothing that says that it always has to be displayed that way. How it is displayed depends on the system, and on some mobile phones for example you don't get a dropdown at all, but a selector that covers most or all of the screen.

If you want to control how your form elements look in such detail, you have to make your own form controls out of regular HTML elements (or find someone else who has already done that).

Comment: Okey, but how then I can achieve an effect where I can select item from list that has ID and then use jQuery to manage this id.click functions? What element I should use then?

Comment: Why the downvote? If you don't explain what it is that you think is wrong, it can't improve the answer.

Answer (score 8):

For future reference if somebody else runs into this problem.
I found a solution that should work in all modern browsers:

```
select{
    scrollbar-width: none; /*For Firefox*/;
    -ms-overflow-style: none;  /*For Internet Explorer 10+*/;
}

select::-webkit-scrollbar { /*For WebKit Browsers*/
    width: 0;
}
```

Basically this way the scrollbar is set to a width of 0 and is hence not displayed.

Comment: Thanks - I used the the answer above by @Mike Young years ago and it worked.  Then it stopped working. `scrollbar-width: none;` works in Firefox v101 atm.

Comment: @Butthosenewbuttonsthough, the example above was missing the second colon in the pseudo element selector (just edited)... I wonder if that was the cause for it not working for you? Regardless it's working okay as of this comment's date in Chrome & Safari (& FF). Also, your username is confusing here :)

Answer (score 5):

**Chrome (and maybe other webkit browsers) only:**

```css
/* you probably want to specify the size if you're going to disable the scrollbar */
select[size]::-webkit-scrollbar {
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<select size=4>
  <option>Mango</option>
  <option>Peach</option>
  <option>Orange</option>
  <option>Banana</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `<div>` to cover the scrollbar if you really want it to disappear.
Although it won't work on IE6, modern browsers do let you put a `<div>` on top of it.

Answer (score 2):

my cross-browser .no-scroll snippet:

```css
.no-scroll::-webkit-scrollbar {display:none;}
.no-scroll::-moz-scrollbar {display:none;}
.no-scroll::-o-scrollbar {display:none;}
.no-scroll::-google-ms-scrollbar {display:none;}
.no-scroll::-khtml-scrollbar {display:none;}
```

```html
<select class="no-scroll" multiple="true">
 <option value="2010" >2010</option>
 <option value="2011" >2011</option>
 <option value="2012" SELECTED>2012</option>
 <option value="2013" >2013</option>
 <option value="2014" >2014</option>
</select>
```

Comment: 2014 doesn't show up as an option. You have to drag downwards to see it, which you'd only do by accident, or middle mouse scroll, which you wouldn't do because it's clearly not scrollable.

Comment: @1j01 add size="5" to the select tag to see all options

Answer (score 0):

Like Guffa said, you cannot reliably get that much control over native controls.  The best way is probably to make a box of elements with radio buttons beside each item, then use labels and JavaScript to make the 'rows' interactive, so clicking on a radio button or label will color the selected row.

Answer (score 0):

Change padding-bottom , i.e may be the simplest possible way .

Answer (score 0):

I worked out Arraxas solution to:

- expand the box to include all elements
- change background & color on hover
- get and alert value on click
- do not keep highlighting selection after clicking

```js
let selElem=document.getElementById('myselect').children[0];
selElem.size=selElem.length;
selElem.value=-1;

selElem.addEventListener('change', e => {
  alert(e.target.value);
  e.target.value=-1;
});
```

```css
#myselect {
  display:inline-block; overflow:hidden; border:solid black 1px;
}

#myselect > select {
  padding:10px; margin:-5px -20px -5px -5px;";
}

#myselect > select > option:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 100px #4A8CF7 inset; color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="myselect">
  <select>
    <option value="2010">2010</option>
    <option value="2011">2011</option>
    <option value="2012">2012</option>
    <option value="2013">2013</option>
    <option value="2014">2014</option>
    <option value="2015">2015</option>
    <option value="2016">2016</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you can't. The SELECT element is rendered at a point beyond the reach of CSS and HTML.
Is it grayed out?

But you can try to add a "size" atribute.

Comment: Okey, but how then I can achieve an effect where I can select item from list that has ID and then use jQuery to manage this id.click functions? What element I should use then?

Comment: adding the "size" attribute still shows the vertical ghost scrollbar