# how to remove the scrolll bar in the gwt listbox?

Tags: gwt

i have a list box in my application, but i don't want to show the
vertical scroll bar on the right side, is there any way to remove it?
here is my code:

```
<g:ListBox visibleItemCount='3' width="15em">
    <g:item>Last 7 Days</g:item>
    <g:item>Last Week</g:item>
    <g:item>Last Month</g:item>
</g:ListBox>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I believe the correct answer to this is simply: "You can't"

The ListBox (HTML Select) vertical scroll bar cannot be completely removed.

You could create your own custom control using a div to do the same thing.  but I believe that may be outside of the abilities of GWT.

[Hide vertical scrollbar in <select> element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4531269/hide-vertical-scrollbar-in-select-element)

Will provide additional information.

Answer (score 0):

I assure you the correct answer to this is simply: "You can".

Just add the line:

```
overflow: hidden !important;
```

to your css style sheet and make sure your visible item count is higher than it's total item count.