# removing scroll elevator from <select> listbox

Tags: jquery, html

How do you remove the elevator from a  element. Ideally, I'd like to use jquery to count the number of elements in the box and if it's greater than n hide the scroll.

Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, teh internets keep telling me you can't do this with CSS/jQuery:

http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=154496 and [Hide vertical scrollbar in <select> element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4531269/hide-vertical-scrollbar-in-select-element)

The `<select>` element is not a "normal" element. The rendering of it doesn't seem to be entirely controllable through CSS. You can set the height/width/et al, but not the overflow attribute. JQuery can only modify the element itself or apply CSS rules after the original DOM has been loaded.

You may be able to find a custom control in the [jQuery UI library](http://jqueryui.com/) that lets you do that.

Comment: ok, it looks like noone's been able to do it so far; looked on google and that seems to be the consensus.

Answer (score 0):

I would just hide the items greater then the number you want show like this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mcgrailm/ES4H3/)

** Edit **

I modified the the above fiddle

here is the html

```
<select name="foo" id="myselect" multiple="true" siz="4">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
    <option>6</option>
</select>
<input type="checkbox" id="mycheckbox" />
```

and the jQuery

```
   $('#myselect').data('removedOptions', $('#myselect > option:gt(3)').detach() );
```

I have stored the options so you can put them back like this

```
var $dropdown = $('#myselect');
  $dropdown.prepend( $dropdown.data('removedOptions') );
```

Answer (score 0):

@mcgrailm: Your solution doesn't work on Chrome.
So, I suggest we can using code with remove() function replace for hide() function.

Here is another version of @mcgrailm:
http://jsfiddle.net/vietean/W4nzn/1/