# How to remove the scroll bar from the select dropdown list

Tags: html, css

I would like to know how to remove the scroll bar from the **select** dropdown list? I have also tried `overflow: hidden;` but it doesn't work in Firefox.

**CSS**:

```
.search_pulldown_txtbox1
{
    height:120px;
    overflow:hidden;
    width: 160px;
    margin-top:8px;
    background-image:none;
    margin-left:10px;
    line-height: 14px;
}
```

**HTML**:

```
<select name="keyword_select" multiple="multiple" class="search_pulldown_txtbox">
    <option> 1</option>
    <option> 2</option>
    <option> 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I would assume that you can't. At best it would be very platform specific. Some aspects of form elements you don't (and shouldn't) have styling control over.

Answer (score 2):

`<select>`s are notoriously difficult to style. Each browser renders them differently. If you really must control the look and feel of a `<select>`, then you may have to resort to custom components built from other HTML elements. E.g. [this one](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_ui_selectmenu_an_aria_accessible_plugin_for_styling_a_html_select/).

Comment: I'm with Box9, mimicking Select functionality and integrating the custom component into your form handling would give you much more consistent flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

[Hide vertical scrollbar in <select> element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4531269/hide-vertical-scrollbar-in-select-element)

Comment: but i am not sure of how many data it will receive.because coming from database.Also i had tried size="3" for testing even doesn;t work