# Is there a way to get rid of vertical scrollbar in dijit.form.multiselect?

Tags: javascript, dojo, scrollbar, multi-select

After looking over the documentation there seems to be no apparent way to get rid of the vertical scrollbar and even when the multiSelect widget is empty (has no options) the scrollbar is still present. If anyone could explain how to remove this it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Dojo's multiselect uses `<select multiple='true'>` and you cannot remove the scrollbar from that html element.

[Hide vertical scrollbar in <select> element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4531269/hide-vertical-scrollbar-in-select-element)