# How to hide scroll bar and change width of select tag

Tags: css

I have a select tag: how can I hide the scroll bar? The other question is how can I increse the width of this select tag

```
<select id="navSelection" size="5"  style="overflow-y :hidden">
    <option value="temp">Temperature</option>
    <option value="flow">Flow</option>
    <option value="press">Pressure</option>
    <option value="cond">Conductivity</option>
</select>
```

`style="overflow-y: hidden"` is not working

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/minagabriel/QZJAG/)

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Hide vertical scrollbar in <select> element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4531269/hide-vertical-scrollbar-in-select-element)
should answer your question about the scrollbar and:

```
#navSelection {
  width: xxxpx;
}
```

Should change the width.

Comment: +1! I was just about to comment the same ques you gave as a duplicate one.. :)

Answer (score 0):

In order to increase the width of the `select` element, you can either write an inline style or set the size using a class or ID:

```
<select style="width: 150px;"></select>
```

OR

```
select { width: 150px; }
```

You cannot override the default browser behavior for displaying a `select` dropdown.