# How to remove horizontal blank space from drop down list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, css, drop-down-menu

I have asp dropdownlist and I wants to remove remaining horizontal blank space(after red line as in the attached image) after its largest content. Is it possible?[image]

Comment: Decrease the width of your dropdown.

Comment: But decreasing the width might cut off the text of other items in the dropdown. Unless the longest text size is known.

Comment: I can not set width as the content could be of any length.

Comment: I think that is a scrollbar - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4531269/hide-vertical-scrollbar-in-select-element

Comment: Is it possible without scrollbar?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think its possible.

A possible workaround is to use a javascript-based alternative:

http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/

Select2 looks and functions better anyway and impresses clients :-)