# How can I customized an expanded select?

Tags: html, google-chrome

I have a select as follows:

```
<select size="5">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
</select>
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6XpHx/

How can I get rid of the shading on the side in Chrome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like so ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6XpHx/5/))

```
select::-webkit-scrollbar 
{
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Does something similar exist for FF & IE?

Comment: @YuriyGalanter Yes, see this [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11433927/1947205).