# Listbox scrollbar won't hide

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to hide the scrollbar on a list box unless it's necessary but can't get it to behave. It seems to always want to show. I am using Chromium, I haven't checked in other browsers whether it behaves.

**HTML**

```
<select size="2">
    <option>item</option>
    <option>item</option>
    <option>item</option>
    <option>item</option>
    <option>item</option>
</select>
```

**CSS**

```
select {
    width: 200px;
    min-height: 400px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jmRmv/

The above code produces:

[image]

Comment: you have mention the min-height:400px
keep it less

Comment: Is this what you looking for : http://jsfiddle.net/jmRmv/4/ I mean you don't want to show the other options ?

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen I want to hide the scrollbar on the right of the box.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4531269/hide-vertical-scrollbar-in-select-element

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a bit of CSS trickery and some JavaScript. It might not be the perfect solution but it works.

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jmRmv/15/).

**CSS**

```
.wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: solid black 1px;
}
.select {
    width: 200px;
    min-height: 50px;
    margin: 0 -20px 0 0;
}
.select.scrolling {
    margin: 0;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <select id="select" class="select" size="2">
        <option>item 1</option>
        <option>item 2</option>
        <option>item 3</option>
        <option>item 4</option>
        <option>item 5</option>
        <option>item 6</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var select = document.getElementById('select');

if (select.clientHeight < select.scrollHeight) {
    select.classList.add('scrolling'); // classList: IE9 and higher
}
```