# Hide scrollbar if array size is less than 5

Tags: html, angularjs, css, scrollbar

I am trying to hide the scrollbar on select if my array has a length of less than 5. I have tried using the CSS styling below but it has no effect on the scrollbar

CSS:

```
.no-scroll::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
.no-scroll::-moz-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
.no-scroll::-o-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
.no-scroll::-google-ms-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
.no-scroll::-khtml-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
```

HTML:

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kdc0nj9s/1)**

Comment: There is no scroll on jsFiddle. Can you share photo?

Comment: @Natiq tested on FF

Comment: if the content is visible you can hide the scrollbar with `overflow:hidden;`

Comment: @Natiq updated it

Comment: @Akis updated it... please check demo. Overflow doesn't work here

Comment: @user4756836, [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4531269/hide-vertical-scrollbar-in-select-element) may help.

Comment: @user4756836 yes but the problem is with your ng-class expression

Answer (score 0):

you have to write Quotation marks outside of the angular expression to execute  properly because you write inside curly braces it's an javascript object notation which means to execute properly it  needs to be in quotation marks as key as value like this because your angular version is 1.0 in this version you have to write like this , but you  can import 1.5 newest 1x version of angular and leave it as you have written or write just like this it's just an angular version problem

```
{'no-scroll': 'colors.length < 5'}
```

[here is the working example](http://jsfiddle.net/kdc0nj9s/8/)