# How to remove <select> vertical scroll bar

Tags: html, css, html-select

I have been searching high and low for a way to remove the vertical scroll bar from an HTML .  In the attached jsFiddle if size value is omitted ther is no scroll bar.  If size=6 or size=7 there is a vertical scroll bar.

I have found several proposed solutions and none of them seem to work.

Does anyone have a solution?

```css
.hideoverflow {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="hideoverflow">
  <select size="7">
    <option id="A">A</option>
    <option id="B">B</option>
    <option id="C">C.....</option>
    <option id="D">D</option>
    <option id="E">E</option>
    <option id="F">F</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, to clarify, you want to limit it to display 7 options but not have a scroll bar when there are more than 7 options?  Did you try overflow:none?

Answer (score 4):

You still can't directly style the <select> element in CSS. It's been a known issue that's described in this slightly dated [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Styling_HTML_forms#The_ugly).

You can however use a display hack to accomplish a similar effect. See [Arraxas' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11433927/7416714) to a similar question. I've taken their answer and changed it to reflect your code.

```css
.hideoverflow {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: solid #DCDFE3 1px
}
.hideoverflow select {
  padding: 4px;
  margin: -5px -20px -5px -5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="hideoverflow">
  <select size="7">
    <option id="A">A</option>
    <option id="B">B</option>
    <option id="C">C.....</option>
    <option id="D">D</option>
    <option id="E">E</option>
    <option id="F">F</option>
  </select>
</div>
```